# Offset from the start of the “mdat” box to the first frame

Tags: vb.net, mp4, video-processing, h.264, file-format

As a personal programming challenge, I have decided to write an MP4 decoder without using external libraries. To achieve this, I am using VB.NET with the .NET Framework 4.8.1 as a WinForms application, and I have purchased the documentation ISO 14496-12.

I have a function that reads the properties of an MP4 file (width, height, etc.), as well as the boxes that are important for extracting frames: Chunk offsets (stco), stsc box (First chunks, Samples per chunk, Sample description index), Sample Sizes, and stts box.

Then, in the second function, I use loops to iterate through these lists and create byte arrays with the correct data. However, I noticed that the first chunk position starts just after the beginning of “mdat”. Upon further inspection, I found that there is readable text (informational metadata) within the “mdat” box, which means it can't be image data or frame data.

[image]

This means **I need some sort of offset from the start of the “mdat” box to the first frame** and to extract the frames.

To try and solve this issue, I attempted to find the start bytes of a frame (the `0, 0, 1 NAL unit`), but unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful in locating them. The NAL unit is absent in multiple files. I read about that NAL unit in the internet. As mentioned, I have even purchased the documentation and searched for various keywords, but I have not yet found a solution. I've googled some possible answers, too.

These are the boxes that I'm parsing:
•   ftyp
•   mdat
•   moov
and in moov:
•   mvhd
•   trak
•   tkhd
•   mdhd
•   hdlr
•   smhd
•   stsd
•   stts
•   stsc
•   stsz
•   stco
According to the documentation, all the other boxes are not mandatory. I couldn't find a ‘saio’ box for auxiliary offsets or a ‘meta’ box.

What drives me nuts is that there are questions on Stack Overflow about decoding an MP4, but no one has this problem.

Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.

---

**Edit 04.06.2023**

```
Private Function Skip_text_metadata_and_find_first_frame() As Integer ' Thanks to VC.One, Stack Overflow; May 30, 2023.
        Dim tempPos As Integer = Me.Mdat_Start_pos
        tempPos += 4
        While (True)
            Dim tempNum As Integer = Get_lower_bits_of_a_byte(Me.Data(tempPos + 4), 5) ' NALU type
            If tempNum <> 5 Then ' 101b is key frame
                Dim size_NALU As UInteger = Me.Data(tempPos + 0) * 256UI * 256UI * 256UI +
                                            Me.Data(tempPos + 1) * 256UI * 256UI +
                                            Me.Data(tempPos + 2) * 256UI +
                                            Me.Data(tempPos + 3)
                tempPos += (CInt(size_NALU) + 4)
                If tempPos > (Me.Mdat_End - 4) Then
                    Return 0
                End If
            Else

                Return (tempPos - Me.Mdat_Start_pos)
                Exit While
            End If
        End While

        Return 0
    End Function
```

*where*

```
Private Shared Function Get_lower_bits_of_a_byte(value As Byte, bitNumber As Integer) As Integer
        Dim two_to_the_bitnumber_minus1 As Integer = CInt(Math.Pow(2, bitNumber)) - 1
        Return value And two_to_the_bitnumber_minus1
    End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to simply use its NALU size to skip that text metadata (actually called **SEI** data). 
You will land on the next NALU which might be a video frame (or else keep skipping by size).
**PS:** There is no `0, 0, 0, 1` **start codes** when NALU is inside an MP4 (replaced by a **size** integer).

Since you are learning MP4 bytes, I will add a more detailed summary...

- **MDAT** is just a collection of NAL units, each unit is prefixed with four bytes for its **size** (length). 
   (MP4 has **Size** before NAL, instead of using **Start-code** as found in raw H.264 or MPEG-TS files).
  *A typical MP4 layout:*
  `[MDAT size in 4 bytes]` --> `[MDAT header in 4 bytes "m","d","a","t"]` then follows NALUs.
  `[NAL #1 size (4 bytes)]` --> `[NAL #1 data]` --> `[NAL #2 size (4 bytes)]` --> `[NAL #2 data]`.
- Your first NAL unit starts after those four `mdat` text bytes. 
  Each NAL starts with `[Size]` (not **start code**).
- The fifth byte is the NAL unit's header (check NAL type, *eg:* is metadata? or video frame?).
- You skip by reading the first four bytes for **NALU's Size** at the start of each NAL. 
   Use the **Size** amount to forward your byte checking position (*eg:* increment it by `+= Size`).

In summary, You have **SEI** as your first NAL unit but if you skip by its **size** you should land on the next NALU which would be a video frame (and is a first frame so it's expected to be a "keyframe"). 
Test on a MP4 file with no audio to simplify the amount of NALU types during your practice.

**Solution:** (with pseudo-code as example)

Your text of `mdat.....ÿÿ}ÜEé` makes it hard to know the actual byte values.

Assuming your data has a layout like...

```
in text:  m  d  a  t  .  .  .  .  .  ÿ  ÿ  }  Ü  E  é
in  hex:  6D 64 61 74 AA BB CC DD XX FF FF 7D DC 45 E9
```

The structure of those bytes means...

- `6D 64 61 74` = four bytes of **ASCII** text as "mdat".
- `AA BB CC DD` = A 32-bit integer for **Size** of NAL unit (*eg:* `00 00 02 72` or decimal **626**).
- `XX` = Is byte a `0x06` (decimal: `6`)? If yes, that means this NAL unit's content is of type: SEI.
  (a byte `0x65` or decimal value of `101` would mean this NAL is a video keyframe).
- `FF FF 7D DC 45 E9 ...etc` = Beginning of SEI content (*eg:* `ÿÿ}ÜEé ...etc`).

The layout looks like you have a NAL unit of **SEI** metadata. 
**SEI** (Supplementary Enhancement Information) is a form of side information that is useful to the decoder but not always needed. If the H264 is inside an MP4 (which itself has an "AVC Config" section) then SEI is not needed by the decoder/player. It can be safely removed in most MP4 files (just some encoder choose to add it in preparation for future use cases like fragmenting etc)...

- The first four dots (`AA BB CC DD`) after letters "mdat" represents four bytes (a 32-bit integer) that you must read in order to get the size of this NAL unit. You can use some built-in **readInt** function or alternatively you can **concat** the four separate byte values into one single integer.
- The fifth byte (`XX`) is the NALU type. Read that byte's value into a variable then check as: 
   `NAL_type = myValue & 0x1F;` where **myValue** is the extracted MP4 byte value.
- Read the integer into a var (*eg:* `size_NALU`) and increase your File/Array position to match `+= size_NALU`. That will move you onto the next NAL unit.
- It is expected to be a keyframe so you can check the NAL type by ignoring its starting four size bytes and then getting that new fifth byte value (as **myValue**), to check NAL type as `type = myValue & 0x1F`.
  A simple trick is that usually if **myValue** is decimal `101` (or hex `"65"`) then it is a keyframe.
  **If true**: then you have found the first keyframe. 
  **If false**: then read its **Size** bytes and use to skip to the next NAL to check that one's type etc.

Example pseudo-code:

```
//# Vars setup
int myPos = 0; //# offset/position within MP4 bytes
int myNum = 0; //# holds temporary numeric values
int size_NALU = 0; //# size of NAL unit in bytes length.
int startPos_of_mdat = some_Num; //# use actual position for start of "mdat"

//# Vars temp numbers to create Integer from (bytes) Array values
int tempA = 0; int tempB = 0; int tempC = 0; int tempD = 0;

//# Main code
int myPos = startPos_of_mdat //# Is pos of the starting "m" letter/byte of "mdat"
myPos += 4; //# Move forward +4 bytes to reach the first NALU (ie: its first size byte)

While( true ) //# search by skipping according to Size, then check NALU type...
{
    myNum = ( MP4_Bytes[ myPos+4 ] & 0x1F ); //# extract the "NALU type" value
    
    if( myNum != 5 ) //# if not keyframe, then skip to next NALU...
    {
        tempA = MP4_Bytes[ myPos+0 ];
        tempB = MP4_Bytes[ myPos+1 ];
        tempC = MP4_Bytes[ myPos+2 ];
        tempD = MP4_Bytes[ myPos+3 ];
        
        //# concat into one 32-bit integer
        size_NALU = ( tempA << 24 | tempB << 16 | tempC << 8 | tempD );
        
        //# update to new position (is the new "skip to" point)
        myPos += (size_NALU + 4); //# must add +4 to account for the extra four bytes of SIZE's integer
        
        //# While loop will repeat until an ELSE is triggered
        //# Can add safety by having an IF to stop whenever myPos is past/larger than the total bytes length. 
        
    }
    else
    {
        //# stop if keyframe is found
        Console.WriteLine( "## Found a Keyframe at offset: " + myPos );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate your help. I was able to adapt your pseudocode to suit my needs, and now I am obtaining the correct offset value for all my mp4 files. It turns out I wasn't too far off with the concept of the ‘NAL unit,’ although it's not exactly the 0 0 0 1 bytes. Next, I will proceed with converting the frames to images (png). However, even with the correct offset, the images are currently appearing black or displaying "snow." I will consult the documentation to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. About the black image... **(1)** Your MP4 first frame isn't black (or fading in from black), right? **(2)** What's the name of the H264 decoder? What does it expect as input when you decode a keyframe (_eg:_ Do you have to put your `[SPS + PPS + IDR/Keyframe]` data into one Array or is it all inside one Struct?). Some decoders do a silent fail if the SPS and/or PPS have an incorrect structure (_eg:_ from bad A-to-B slicing points missing some bytes).

Comment: **(3)** If the NAL unit you're decoding is not a keyframe (is P or B frame) then your decoder might require the other in-between frames, starting from the nearest last keyframe up to this current decoded frame.

Comment: 1) My saved images contain a narrow strip of "snow" at the top and are black below the strip. The width of the stripe does vary a little.

Comment: 2) it's H.264/AVC in all files I tested

Comment: I haven't done anything of this `SPS + PPS + IDR/Keyframe` so far. First, I decompressed the following 5 lists, so all lists contain the same number of items.
- SampleSizes
- Chunkoffsets
- Stsc.First_chunks
- Stsc.Samples_per_chunk
- Stsc.Sample_description_index

After that, I find the offset we discussed here.

After that I create a byte array as big as the current sample size is. I read from the offset into the file, with this SampleSize. I pass the byte array to a function that creates an image using simple .NET methods. But was clear to me that this is not enough.

Comment: 4) Why I just logged in: I looked at 5 video files, what the first bytes are, where our offset points.

On 3 videos, the bytes are {101, 136, 132, 0}; 

but on the fourth, they are {101, 136, 132, 6}; 

and on the fifth, I got {0, 0, 89, 44}, because your function returned  0. Nal unit was 3, but `tempPos > Mdat_End` was true so it returned. Is that ok?

Comment: 4) I post the function

Comment: _"I pass the byte array to a function that creates an image using simple .NET methods"_ I don't use .Net that is why I ask what name your decoder/API is called? Usually the simplest test is to decode a keyframe (type: hex **0x65** or decimal **101**), since it's a complete image with no missing parts (like how a P or B frame is incomplete and needs prediction data). To decode a keyframe most decoders expect NALUs of the **SPS** data  followed by **PPS** data and then finally the keyframe data all as one package.

Comment: `[SPS + PPS + IDR/Keyframe]` will initialize the decoder and it can be ready for other frame types (P or B) by using the now decoded keyframe to predict their missing parts. Does your decoder function accept NALU data with start codes? If yes, see if it can decode the following data. Put into an Array variable then send array to your decoder...

Comment: `[ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0xC0, 0x1E, 0xDD, 0xEC, 0x04, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F, 0x03, 0xC5, 0x8B, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, 0xCE, 0x0F, 0x2C, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x65, 0x88, 0x84, 0x04, 0xBC, 0x46, 0x28, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x7D, 0x47, 0x00, 0x01, 0x7D, 0x78, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x22, 0x3D, 0x80 ]`

Comment: I have not implemented a ready-made decoder. The project started experimentally, then later I bought the documentation and worked with it. After that I came across the problem we discussed here. So yes, I will have to write a decoder. So far, I have used (experimentally) a function that takes the byte array. I didn't know at first that and how bytes are encoded.
I see the byte array starting with `[101, 136, 132,]`.
**As a next step I have to read up on P- and B-frames.**
And this is what I don't understand: `[SPS + PPS + IDR/Keyframe]`.
Tomorrow is Saturday, I'll be learning this.